# Ng-if not responding to model changes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm co-developing a login system UI in an angular app and I would like the sign-up and log-in menus to appear depending on a button press. I could do this in the controller with a .on method, but apparently that's bad practice in terms of using angular properly.

My code is as follows (cut out unnecessary bits):

```
<section ng-model="login" ng-init="login=true">
    <section ng-if="login">
        LOGIN CONTENT
        <button ng-click="login = !login">Sign up for an account</button>
    </section>
    <section ng-if="!login">
        SIGN UP CONTENT
    </section>
</section>
```

I've no clue what I'm doing wrong, or if this is even the proper angular way of doing it.

Comment: ngIf creates isolated scope so it doesnt update 'login' on the controller. You need a dot in your model, i.e. someModel.login.

Comment: @Zyga I.e.: <ng-model="login.login" ng-init="login.login = true"? and then <ng-if="login.login>

Comment: something like that yes, maybe with better naming :) you will actually need to create 'login' object with 'login' property if you get my drift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't put `ng-model` on your first section tag.
2. Declare `$scope.params = {}`; in your controller, and then set its parameter `login` to `true`:

---

Check [**this Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/xjxu92m7/).

```
<section ng-init="params.login = true">
  <section ng-if="params.login">
    <button ng-click="params.login = !params.login">Sign up for an account</button>
    LOGIN CONTENT
  </section>
  <section ng-if="!params.login">
    SIGN UP CONTENT
  </section>
  login is: {{params.login}}
</section>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reasons why the button ought to be outside of the sections?

Answer (score 2):

Create an object with the login field. Use it in the login, so the model will get updated.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.user ={};
   
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="dobController">
  
  <section ng-model="user.login" ng-init="user.login=true">
    <section ng-if="user.login">
      LOGIN CONTENT
      <button ng-click="user.login = !user.login">Sign up for an account</button>
    </section>
    <section ng-if="!user.login">
      SIGN UP CONTENT
    </section>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, because ngIf directive creates isolated scope, you need a dot in your model, otherwise changes done to the primitive value will not "propagate" back to controller.

So create an object rather than primitive in controller, i.e.

`$scope.someModel = { login: true};`

and reference that in HTML as `"someModel.login"`. This way you could also get rid of ngInit as its not necessarily a good use case for it.